# Restrict user to access admin

Tags: magento-1, ce-1.9.2.3, admin-user

We have a website and its working perfectly fine. We want to block users so they can't login into our admin section.

We have one public IP in our factory premises to access the internet and we locally make server to access the internet on other computers.

We want our website admin login section only accessibly within factory premises and no one can access the admin login section out of the factory or only specific registered user can login into admin section out the factory as well like our CEO and our project manager.

is this feature possible in Magento 1.9.2.3?

Hope you people understand my problem.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working perfectly fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Comment: Now only problem is remaining how can we allow some user by "Email or Username" to login into admin at outside the factory.

Comment: You need to whitelist their IPs also, or use a password and username in the .htaccess for these people

Comment: can you please explain little bit more or give me some example?

Comment: If they have a static IP then you can add this IP also. With .htaccess im not sure if you can specifically block access to the backend only

Comment: Check my change above in my answer, this might be useful if you change your backend path to something weird

Comment: no they have dynamic IP, basically i want my CEO and Project manager only  can open the backend at outside the factory as well.

Comment: Just move the backend to a different path, and make a login for them. Surely that should be enough.

Comment: i  didn't understand can you please explain with example please?

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit your `.htaccess` file and add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.123.123.123
```

Where **123.123.123.123** is your IP address from your factory.
This below is addon to route to another path as the usual path is not recommended anyway. So you could use anything instead of /admin to access the backend.

So for your needs you could change it to something cryptic and then make user accounts for CEO and Project manager. It will barely happen that someone tries something cryptic to enter your backend. Just replace **/admin** below with the new URL for the backend and then it will be accessible there.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// %{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: i just need to replace the IP address  that i want to access the admin login access and nothing to give any other information.

Comment: Only the IP you are using to access it, but of course then you need a login for Magento

Comment: i apply the same code and replace the IP but its give an error "Internal Server Error".

Comment: Here above my example with the admin path